# why is \numberwithin{figure}{chapter} not working in appendix？

Tags: numbering, captions, counters

I want to use

`\numberwithin{figure}{section}` for main text

and

`\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}` for Appendix

but in Appenix it does not work well, looks like this:

[image]

more strange is，

whenn I use 
`\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}` for main text

and 
`\numberwithin{figure}{section}` for Appendix

they both work well...

Can someone help me?

MWE for test:

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,% not needed because default       
    oneside,        
    12pt,               
    onecolumn,          
    openright,% nonsense after oneside or before openay
    openany,% nonsense after onecolumn
    parskip=full*,      
    headsepline,        
    footsepline,        
    bibliography=totoc,
    numbers=noenddot,   
    appendixprefix
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%---------------------------------------------------------
%\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter}

\section{section1}

 \begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics*{testfig.png}
    \caption{Fig for Test}
 \end{figure}

\section{section2}

 \begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics*{testfig.png}
    \caption{Fig for Test}
 \end{figure}


\appendix
%---------------------------------------------------------
%\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
%---------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{the first chapter in appendix}


\section{first sec in appendix}

 \begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics*{testfig.png}
    \caption{Fig for Test}
 \end{figure}

\section{second sec in appendix}

 \begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics*{testfig.png}
    \caption{Fig for Test}
 \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is independent from the appendix or KOMA-Script:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter}

\section{section1}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics*{example-image}
  \caption{Fig for Test}
\end{figure}

\section{section2}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics*{example-image}
  \caption{Fig for Test}
\end{figure}

\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}

\chapter{another chapter}

\section{first sec after number change}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics*{example-image}
  \caption{Fig for Test}
\end{figure}

\section{second after number change}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics*{example-image}
  \caption{Fig for Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`\numberwithin` does not remove the counter from the resetlist of the parent counter of a previous `\numberwithin`. So the `\section` commands still resets the `figure` counter. You have to remove it yourself. You can either use package `chngcntr`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter}

\section{section1}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics*{example-image}
  \caption{Fig for Test}
\end{figure}

\section{section2}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics*{example-image}
  \caption{Fig for Test}
\end{figure}

\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}

\chapter{another chapter}

\section{first sec after number change}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics*{example-image}
  \caption{Fig for Test}
\end{figure}

\section{second after number change}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics*{example-image}
  \caption{Fig for Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Or you can use KOMA-Script's `\@removefromreset`:

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,% not needed because default       
    oneside,        
    12pt,               
    onecolumn,          
    openright,% nonsense after oneside or before openay
    openany,% nonsense after onecolumn
    parskip=full*,      
    headsepline,        
    footsepline,        
    bibliography=totoc,
    numbers=noenddot,   
    appendixprefix
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%---------------------------------------------------------
%\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter}

\section{section1}

 \begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics*{example-image}
    \caption{Fig for Test}
 \end{figure}

\section{section2}

 \begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics*{example-image}
    \caption{Fig for Test}
 \end{figure}


\appendix
%---------------------------------------------------------
%\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\csname @removefromreset\endcsname{figure}{section}% added
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
%---------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{the first chapter in appendix}


\section{first sec in appendix}

 \begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics*{example-image}
    \caption{Fig for Test}
 \end{figure}

\section{second sec in appendix}

 \begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics*{example-image}
    \caption{Fig for Test}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You helped me again！！ Worship you