# Confusing usage of chngcntr package

Tags: numbering, theorems, counters

I'm not fully understanding how `chngcntr` works. I've attached an example that hopefully explains my confusion, along with the source code, of course.

What I want is for the first section to be numbered as `1.1, 1.2,...` the second as `2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.2,...` and then the third back to `3.1, 3.2, ...`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}

\section{Labels 1.1, 1.2, ...}
\begin{thm} Theorem 1 \end{thm}
\subsection{New Subsection \textit{Does Not} Change Counter}
\begin{thm} Theorem 2 \end{thm}
\subsection{And Again}
\begin{thm} Theorem 3 \end{thm}

------------------------------

\section{Labels 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.1, ...}
\counterwithin{thm}{subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{thm} Theorem 1 \end{thm}
\begin{thm} Theorem 2 \end{thm}
\subsection{New Subsection \textit{Does} Change Counter}
\begin{thm} Theorem 3 \end{thm}
\begin{thm} Theorem 4 \end{thm}

------------------------------

\section{Now I Try to Go Back to the First Case...}
\counterwithin{thm}{section}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{thm} Theorem 1 \end{thm}
\subsection{Subsection 2 -- Counter Is Reset to the Start}
\begin{thm} Theorem 2 \end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image: Display]

Comment: Confusing is rather your scheme of numbering

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396193/why-is-numberwithinfigurechapter-not-working-in-appendix/396194#396194

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the non-recommended numbering scheme...

`\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]` subjects the `thm` counter to being reset by `section`.

Now, `\counterwithin{thm}{subsection}` sets `thm` on the reset list of `subsection` too. This is 'ok' as long as `\subsection` is used.

Switching back with

`\counterwithin{thm}{section}`

is not sufficient later on, since `thm` is still on the reset list of `subsection`, so any unstarred `\subsection` command will reset the `thm` counter. This is wrong and not requested, so the `thm` counter must be removed from the reset list first:

```
\counterwithout{thm}{subsection}
\counterwithin{thm}{section}
```

to revert the numbering and resetting.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Labels 1.1, 1.2, ...}
\begin{thm} Theorem 1 \end{thm}
\subsection{New Subsection \textit{Does Not} Change Counter}
\begin{thm} Theorem 2 \end{thm}
\subsection{And Again}
\begin{thm} Theorem 3 \end{thm}

------------------------------

\section{Labels 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.1, ...}
\counterwithin{thm}{subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{thm} Theorem 1 \end{thm}
\begin{thm} Theorem 2 \end{thm}
\subsection{New Subsection \textit{Does} Change Counter}
\begin{thm} Theorem 3 \end{thm}
\begin{thm} Theorem 4 \end{thm}

------------------------------

\section{Now I Try to Go Back to the First Case...}
\counterwithout{thm}{subsection}
\counterwithin{thm}{section}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{thm} Theorem 1 \end{thm}
\subsection{Subsection 2 -- Counter Is Reset to the Start}
\begin{thm} Theorem 2 \end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see: the suffix `-in`/`-out` works **a bit** like a start/stop? That is the bit that I wasn't understanding (the documentation didn't make this clear *to me*).

Comment: @SamT: start/stop is the wrong term. Push and pull is better ;-) And the documentation is pretty clear, in my point of view

Comment: I don't know what push/pull would mean in this sense =P -- once you've explained it, I can see what the documentation means. However, you have 125k rep on here, and I have 67 (plus association bonus), so it's to be expected that you understand it better than me! =P

Comment: @SamT: `\counterwithin` → **push** the counter on the reset list, `\counterwithout` → **pull** the counter from the reset list

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks very much, that's very helpful! :)

Comment: Incidentally, as you mentioned, an unusual numbering system. The reason for this is that one of my sections is much longer than the other (the main part of the proof), and is broken into sub- and subsubsections. It helps the reading to have these labelled as 3.2.1, 3.3.4, ... -- this would be unnecessary (/unhelpful) for the remaining sections :)

Comment: @SamT: It is your choice, of course. I would not use, however. Rather omit the `\subsection` or even `\subsubsection - wise numbering. When I read a reference like `2.1` I don't expect it to find it deeply hidden in `subsubsection 2.1.1.4` etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... The *idea* of why I'm doing this is that I can reference Theorem 3.2.2, and it's in Section 3.2, instead of referencing Theorem 3.18 and it's in Section 3, but no real idea where. Only for this one section do I use `\subsubsection`. Isn't this what you're saying?